# Multiple python pools for processing big CSV files in chunks

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multiprocessing

I am trying to parse multiple Big Data csv files in chunks so that I can use multiprocessing capabilities in python.

Main:

```
directory = os.fsencode('bigdata/')

p = mp.Pool(2)
for file in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)               
    p.apply_async(process_csv, [filename, csvfolder])

p.close()
p.join()

print('p Done!')
```

Function to process each CSV in parallel:

```
def process_csv(filename, csvfolder):
    data_chunks = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=10000)
    
    q = mp.Pool(2)
    for chunk in data_chunks:
         q.apply_async(process_data_chunk, [chunk])

    q.close()
    q.join()
    print('q done!')
```

Function to process each chunk in parallel:

```
def process_data_chunk(chunk):
    # process chunk and export to intermediate csv file
```

My aim was to do this to generate much smaller CSV files that I would then able to merge easily.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I am only able to use either of the pools. If both are present, the script just ends with no output or errors. No csv files are generated. But if I use only Pool p or only Pool q, the csv files are generated. What's the reason?

Comment: would each chunk be its separate csv file?

Comment: In the process_data_chunk method, each chunk would be processed and aggregated and then exported to a separate CSV file.

Comment: You are creating a process pool inside a process pool. That is rife with race conditions. So, don't do that. Also, you're calling the `.apply_async` method on the pools without handling any exceptions/errors that could arise. Make sure to handle those.

Comment: Instead, would the better approach be to create a set of processes for `process_csv` and then use pools for the chunks?